# Argument passed to call that takes no arguments - TabView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I created a new SwiftUI file and using xcode, I literally added the default tabview and it is throwing an error. I attempted to reproduce this error by creating a new Xcode project but it is working perfectly. If I delete the TabView code, it builds fine.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TabView: View {
    
    @State var tabSelection = 0
    var body: some View {
        Text("wowcool")
      
        TabView(selection: .constant(1)) {
            Text("Tab Content 1").tabItem { Text("Tab Label 1") }.tag(1)
            Text("Tab Content 2").tabItem { Text("Tab Label 2") }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct TabView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabView()
    }
}
```

Below is what I am getting:

[image]

Attempts to fix:

1. Restarted Xcode
2. Cleaned Project
3. Deleted Derived data
4. Restarted computer

Currently on Xcode 13.3 and macOS 12.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding SwiftUI's TabView. Rename your view to something else.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to type conflicts (you named your custom view same as system one), so

Solution 1:

```
struct MyTabView: View {

   ...
        TabView(selection: .constant(1)) {

   ...
}
```

Solution 2:

```
struct TabView: View {

   ...
        SwiftUI.TabView(selection: .constant(1)) {

   ...
}
```

*Note: I would recommend *solution 1* always and do not use same names as system types.*